# C close() : Invalid argument

Tags: c, linux, pipe, invalid-argument

Sorry per advance for my english, i'm not english native and be indulgent i'm also a student.

I'm trying to recreate the pipe function in C, but i have a problem when i try to close pipe fd before the `dup2()`, the function `close()` return me an error `Ïnvalid argument`, i have already check if my fd is valid and created by `pipe()`.

But now I don't understand why my FD used as argument is not accepted by `close()` in my son process

After this on my parent process my function `close()` return me an undefined error

here is what the console returns to me when I run my program

> close 1 2st cmd: Undefined error: 0

> close 1 1st cmd: Invalid argument

```
pid_t       pid;
t_command   *cmd;
int         pipe_fd[2];

if (pipe(pipe_fd) == -1)
    perror_exit("pipe");

cmd = list->first;
if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
    perror_exit("fork");
if (pid == 0)
{
    /* Code fils */
    cmd = cmd->next;
    if (!close(pipe_fd[1]))
        perror_exit("close 1 1st cmd");
    if (!dup2(pipe_fd[0], STDIN_FILENO))
        perror_exit("dup2 1st cmd");
    if (!close(pipe_fd[0]))
        perror_exit("close 2 1st cmd");
    if (!execve(cmd->path_exec, cmd->tab_cmd, envp))
        perror_exit("execve 1st cmd");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);     
}
/* Code parent */
//waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);
if (!close(pipe_fd[0]))
    perror_exit("close 1 2st cmd");
if (!dup2(pipe_fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO))
    perror_exit("dup2 2st cmd");
if (!close(pipe_fd[1]))
    perror_exit("close 2 2st cmd");
if (!execve(cmd->path_exec, cmd->tab_cmd, envp))
    perror_exit("execve 2st cmd");
```

Comment: The [close manual](https://linux.die.net/man/2/close) tells you what it returns: "*returns zero on success. On error, -1 is returned*". You are not checking the right error condition.

Comment: With ```if (!close(pipe_fd[0])```, i will test if close return -1 right ?

Comment: No. That's not how C works. `0` is evaluated to be false and everything else is true (including `-1`).

Comment: It might be helpful to break your `if (!close(...))` into `ret = close(...); If (!ret) printf("ret=%d, err=%s\n", ret, strerror(errno))`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @U.Windl indeed it allows to have more information in case of error, I will keep this error handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [close manual](https://linux.die.net/man/2/close)

> **Return Value**
>
> close() returns zero on success. On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

That means you are checking for the wrong error condition. Should be:

```
if (close(pipe_fd[1]) == -1)
```

Same for the other `close`, `dup2` and `execve` calls.